# submit() not working for first time in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, thickbox

I am developing an e-commerce site.. and now I got stuck at one point.. When I submit the form ,it doesn't submits on the **first click**, and i need to give a second click to get it working... I have used anchor tag to submit my data bcoz I want to show the data inside thickbox(iframe)...

```
  View file
  <%= form_for :order, :url => populate_orders_url ,:html => { :class => "data# product.id}"},:method => "post",:remote => true do |f| %>

 // data 
//submit button


    <a href="/cart?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=380&width=1000&modal=false"  onclick="$('.data<%= product.id %>').submit().trigger.reload();"   class="thickbox cart_button"></a>

 orders controller.rb
 def populate
  @order = current_order(true)

  params[:products].each do |product_id,variant_id|
    quantity = params[:quantity].to_i if !params[:quantity].is_a?(Hash)
    quantity = params[:quantity][variant_id].to_i if params[:quantity].is_a?(Hash)
    @order.add_variant(Variant.find(variant_id), quantity, ad_hoc_option_value_ids, product_customizations) if quantity > 0
  end if params[:products]

  params[:variants].each do |variant_id, quantity|
    quantity = quantity.to_i
    @order.add_variant(Variant.find(variant_id), quantity, ad_hoc_option_value_ids, product_customizations) if quantity > 0
  end if params[:variants]

  fire_event('spree.cart.add')
  fire_event('spree.order.contents_changed')

  redirect_to cart 

end
```

I have seen in firebug and populate method is processed but it not sending data into cart and it showing me empty cart..and cart is processing...

Answer (score 0):

You are sending **ajax request**,remove `:remote => true` option from form and check.

Comment: yes I know that,but if I remove it, cart page will not open in thickbox..... I want to open it in thickbox..

Comment: redirect_to can't work as per my knowledge for ajax request,you have to render some js and `ajax:success` redirect to cart page using javascript window or write some appropriate js.